# How to Increment a number, in listView when clicking on Button

Tags: android, listview

I'm new to Android, and i'm developing an application where users can like or dislike a post, when the user dislikes the post likes number-- if the user likes number++.

the problem is that when I press the button it works, but it doesn't work for some other items, and when I scroll down or up I lose the info, and it will be mixed all over the other items

I'm using an adapter view for my list view which look like this :

```
public adapter(Context context, ArrayList<statisticitem> questionaires) {
   super(context, 0, questionaires);
}
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

   final statisticitem c = getItem(position);    


   if (convertView == null) {
      convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.custom, parent, false);

   }

   TextView text1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
   final TextView text2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
   TextView text3 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
   ImageView like = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);


   text1.setText(c.getIdQuestion());

   like.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

           likes++;

           text2.setText("likes :"+likes);


        }
 });




   return convertView;
}

}
```

the Main Activity where I have the Listview :

```
ListView list1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
  lists  = new ArrayList<statisticitem>();
  for (int i=0;i<10;i++) {  
  statisticitem s = new statisticitem();
  s.setIdQuestion("Question"+i);
  lists.add(s);
  }

    adapter adapter = new adapter(MainActivity.this, (ArrayList<statisticitem>) lists);
    list1.setAdapter(adapter);


}
```

Using ViewHolder :

```js
public class adapter extends ArrayAdapter<statisticitem> {

int likes;

public adapter(Context context, ArrayList<statisticitem> questionaires) {
   super(context, 0, questionaires);
}
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
   
   final ViewHolder holder;

   if (convertView == null) {
      convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.custom, parent, false);

      holder = new ViewHolder();
     holder.text1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
     holder.button = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
     holder.text2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView2); 
     convertView.setTag(holder);
   }
   else {
    holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
   }
   
   final statisticitem s = getItem(position); 
 
   if (s !=null)
   {
    holder.text1.setText(s.getIdQuestion());
    
    holder.button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
       likes++;
      holder.text2.setText("yasser"); 
       
      }
     });
    
    
   }
  




   return convertView;
}

}
```

My ViewHolder class :

```
public class ViewHolder {
TextView text1;
TextView text2;
ImageView button;
```

}

And i'm having always the same problem, can you please suggest me anything, or help me out with this, thanks

Comment: You really should use a uppercase letter for your class, so you can see a difference to your object. Like `Adapter adaper = new Adapter()`. Also: Are you extending some sort of Adapter? In your case, maybe a ArrayAdapter? It looks like you just defined your own class, but thats not automatically an adapter, even if you call it adapter.

Comment: Where is the likes variable instanciated, what is its scope?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the ViewHolder pattern for this. The ListView keeps recycling its views and the data goes nuts. Please refer to this:

http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html#ViewHolder

Comment: Can you please give an example in my Case if you wish

Comment: I updated the post, with using HolderView, and I'm facing the same problem

Answer (score 0):

You have to store the value in the correct location. I think in your case in the statisticitem. So get the statisticitem corresponding to the item via the items position and store it there. Also retrieve it there when you update your view.

The viewHolder pattern is nice, but does not resolve your problem. Think about your data structure. To which object does the "likes" variable belong to? Where do you save it and retrieve it from to have the correct value. It should have nothing to do with your view.

Comment: I updated the post, with using HolderView, and I'm facing the same problem

Answer (score -1):

You can create a static variable for the like/dislike count,

```
private static int likeCount = 0;
```

Then update the value within like/dislike event.

Comment: Sorry, but this is a one-shot solution and not the right way to solve such a problem with android ListView